# How do I report restricted stock unit (RSU) income that has vested in multiple states

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, rsu

In 2016, when I started at my current employer, I received a grant of Restricted Stock Units (RSUs) that vests over 4 years. I was employed in our NY office 2016-2018 and San Francisco Office 2016-present.

None of my RSUs were "delivered" until 2019, when the company went public. As such, this is the first year that RSUs are shown on my W-2 and need to be reported on my return.

**Given my employment in multiple states, how much RSU income do I report on each *state* tax return?** Do I pro-rate the amount based on the number of days employed in each location? For example, if my RSU grant is wroth $100K and I was employed for 300 days in NY and 300 days in CA, would I report $50K on each state's return?

Comment: As far as I know, vesting isn't a taxable event. You didn't get any stock until 2019, so wherever you lived in 2019 is where you report all the income.

Comment: RSU income is usually reported on your  W2. Which state did your company report the income to on your W2?

Comment: @ThePhoton The full amount is reported for both states on my w2. In fact, it looks like they reported the full RSU amount + my salary for both states. This doesn't make sense because my salary should definitely only be reported in CA.

Comment: @ThePhoton That was my thought too, but in most cases vesting means the shares are transferred to the employee and they are free to do whatever they want with them. That doesn't seem to have been the case here.

Comment: @CraigW That's correct. The RSUs had a time condition (vesting over 4 years) and a liquidity event condition (IPO, acquisition, etc.)

Comment: @ThePhoton Cite? Vesting and distribution are two different things, though usually they are (nearly) simultaneous. An RSU has no value itself, so shouldn't be taxed until a share of stock is actually distributed in its place.

Comment: @chepner, I think you're right. In this scenario, with a private company, the distribution can be separate from the vesting. That puts the answer to the question outside my knowledge.

Comment: @rahimftd You may want to contact your company for clarification. Based on the information in the question, I don't think there is any reason for any income to have been reported to NY in 2019.

Comment: @chepner Not sure about NY, but if the states were reversed, CA would still want their share: https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/misc/1004.html#E-Restricted-Stock-

Comment: @CraigW That link deals with restricted stock, which is distinct from restricted stock units.

Comment: @chepner The table at the bottom refers to them as restricted stock units (RSUs) though. In any case I'm sure CA will want to tax them even if you're not a resident when you receive them.

Comment: The page also makes multiple references to the income being the difference between the fair market value of the stock and the price you paid. Even if the price you paid could be $0, it still seems to imply the receipt of actual shares of stock that you can sell, which you *don't* receive when an RSU vests.

Comment: [This page](https://www.moneycrashers.com/restricted-stock-units-rsu-taxation/) (which I admit is far from definitive) indicates that restricted stock is actual stock that transfers to the recipient immediately upon vesting, while a vested RSU is simply *eligible* for distribution as actual stock to the recipient. It specifically notes (point 4 under "Advantages of RSUs") that you can perf taxation beyond the vesting date by delaying the issue of the actual shares. In the OP's case, this delay is caused by the fact that the stock didn't *exist* yet on the vesting date.

Comment: (For "perf" in the preceding comment, read "defer".)